# Googl sheets copy row script problem (4th line)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use multiple versions of this script but the target tab at the end of the 4th line is the problem. But it only copies to the target tab from the 4th line of the last file.

```
function CopyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var FormResponses = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var AssetGoodPurchase = ss.getSheetByName("Assets/Goods Purchase")

  var Whatkindofapurchaseareyoumaking = AssetGoodPurchase.getRange(1,13).getValue();
  AssetGoodPurchase.getRange("A2:C1000").clear();
  
  var lastrow = FormResponses.getLastRow() + 1;
  var FoundRecord = false;

  for(var j = 2; j < lastrow; j++)
  {
    if(FormResponses.getRange(j,13).getValue() ==Whatkindofapurchaseareyoumaking)
    {
      var nextRow = AssetGoodPurchase.getLastRow() +1;
      var GetCopyRange = FormResponses.getRange('A' + j + ':AL' + j);
      GetCopyRange.copyTo(AssetGoodPurchase.getRange(nextRow, 1));
      FoundRecord = true;
    }


  }
  if(FoundRecord == false)
  {
    AssetGoodPurchase.getRange(2,1).setValue(['(NO RECORDS FOUND)']);
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe simplify your question to be fundamentally where the issue is with a basic spreadsheet without all your custom names/sheets. A shared sheet is always nice to help illustrate too. Copying data is pretty routine, so it shouldn't be hard to fix if your question was broken down.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is not so clear but what I could see is:

1. Since the copying logic is subject to the condition,

`if(FormResponses.getRange(j,13).getValue() ==Whatkindofapurchaseareyoumaking)`

being true, you can see if that condition is false for 2nd and 3rd row of your source data.